# How did I earn "Edit community wikis" privilege

Tags: discussion, support

I just noticed that I was recently (yesterday) given the "Edit community wikis" privilege.

The description about the "Edit community wikis" privilege says that the privilege is given when the user has 100 reputation points.

I joined this SE site (EL&U) about 2 and a half years ago and was given 100 "Association Bonus" points at that time, and I have only earned 13 additional reputation points since then (total 113).

So, what triggered the "Edit community wikis" privilege at this time?

---

**Edit**

```
113 Reputation  

+2    2 days ago 20:47   edit    Image is to pixelated as a song is to ___?  
+10   Jul 22 '13 19:57   upvote  How to indicate possession when using abbreviation “Dr.”  
+100  May 3  '13 22:32   assoc   Association Bonus
```

The three entries add up to 112. The extra point (total 113) is because new accounts always begin with 1 point (I think).

The odd thing to me, is that if the "Association Bonus" counts toward the 100 required points, the privilege should have been given when (shortly after) I signed up in May 2013. And if the "Association Bonus" DOESN'T count, then I never earned anywhere near enough reputation points.

The only thing I can think of, is that:

1. The "Edit community wikis" privilege is a brand new privilege, or
2. The reputation point requirement for the "Edit community wikis" privilege has recently changed (lowered).

and I happen to already meet the reputation point requirement.

I was notified about this privilege in the "Achievements" notification list a few days ago. I was able to click on the entry in the notification list to see info about the privilege, but that notification entry is now gone. I checked my "privileges", and I do have that privilege shown.

Another thing, when I got this notification, I was notified that I now have this privilege on 2 SE sites: EL&U, and another site that I don't recall, and since the notification is now gone, I can't tell which other site it was. The only details I can remember are that it was a site I signed up for about 2 years ago, and that I currently have between 125 and 150 (~135) reputation points.

Comment: You have 113 points. Points tend to be distributed in factors of 5, with few exceptions. So why do you have a prime number of points? My guess: two years ago you earned the 100 rep bonus, then posted an answer which was downvoted (-2), leaving you at 98. Now, you came back and posted another answer which was accepted or thrice-upvoted (+15), meaning you *crossed the 100 pt threshold*, triggering the privilege and leaving you with 113 points. That's all pure speculation; we could take a look at your account history to support or invalidate the theory.

Comment: @DanBron Good guess, but [wrong](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/43682/kevin-fegan?tab=reputation)...

Comment: @curiousdanni Whew! Good thing I C'd my A with that disclaimer at the end ;) Also, I haven't looked at Kevin's history, on the mobile app you link just takes me to his profile, not to any specific element.

Comment: I posted my reputation history and some more information above in an edit to the question.

Comment: Whenever you join a community, it congratulates you and says you earned that privilege. If you haven't dismissed the message, it'll show up, even if that's 100 years later.